# Query on where to locate files in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I installed the Front-End Basic and Login / Registration Scaffolding for Laravel Passport using the command php artisan ui react --auth.

Just for curiosity sake and not being able to find them. Where can I exactly find the files I installed using that command.

[image: Default Page when running Npm run dev]

Specifically this page.

This may seem dumb, but I cant just cant find them.
Thank you for the time!

I've skimmed through the files and still no luck.

Comment: That seems to be the Vite server's page, there really is no need to access/change it, this will only show in development.

Comment: Oh okay, Thank you for that!